# I need to add vertical side bars on all the screens of my app

Tags: android

[image: This is what is desired]

I need to add these on all the screens. Is there a good way of doing it ?

I tried using with textfields but that didn't work

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="11dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_red"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="11dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"/>
```

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried? What have you already found online?

Comment: Tried with textviews but did not get what I wanted

Comment: <TextView
        android:layout_width="11dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/plastc_light_red"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="11dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/plastc_light_blue"/>

Comment: </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="11dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/green"/>

Comment: It would be better to edit your question and add the code there in a section at the bottom called **EDIT**. Users may not think to look in the comments to find your code.

Comment: I added some code for clarity.